# AchartEngine How insert the data in?

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine, batterylevel

Well, it's about 1 mounth i try to implement a battery graph in my application.. Simply a chart that monitoring the battery state during a day (o more)... I found the AchartEngine framework but really, there are too much files for me and i can't understand what i have to change to have what i want... I opened the demo folder and i found some example graphs. I think that the best in my case it's the `Average Temperature` example graph. This is its code

```
  /**
   * Executes the chart demo.
   * 
   * @param context the context
   * @return the built intent
   */
  public Intent execute(Context context) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Crete" };
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }); // X Values
    }
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 10, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 26, 26, 23, 18, 14, 11 }); // Y Values
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW };
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND,
        PointStyle.TRIANGLE, PointStyle.SQUARE };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
    }
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Average temperature", "Month", "Temperature", 0.5, 12.5, -10, 40,
        Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
    XYSeries series = dataset.getSeriesAt(0);
    series.addAnnotation("Vacation", 6, 30);
    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer,
        "Average temperature");
    return intent;
  }

}
```

If my idea is correct what i want would be something like

```
values.add(new double[] { batterylevel }); // Chart line Values
```

Right?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. However, the ideal way to actually develop against AChartEngine is to include the jar in your classpath and start writing some code against its APIs. You will see that you will have to "mess" with less files.